# Add javascript and CSS to footer

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, performance

Im looking to improve my page load time/ranking and according to PageSpeed Insights.. the problem is a lot of my scripts/css are render blocking. How can i successfully use wp_enqueue_script() to help me get the bulk of my scripts into my footer instead of my header (wordpress).

[subject site](http://guytgunterappliances.com)

CSS examples

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php  echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/<?php  echo get_current_theme()  ?>/style-jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php  echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/<?php  echo get_current_theme()  ?>/style-prettyPhotoCSS.php" type="text/css" />
```

Script Example

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1'></script>
```

Comment: change output placement in template(s)

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain how to do this? I've never done this before

Comment: you actually want css in the head, js in the foot.

Comment: have you read the docs that explain how `wp_enqueue_script` works? And how scripts get printed to the page? Is well documented

Comment: BTW...css should not go in footer or page won't know how to set style when loading html. CSS should always be in head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) would be something like this;

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_scripts');
function load_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/modernizr.custom-2.6.2.min.js', array('jquery'), '0.1', true );
}
```

The last true of the function place the script call in the footer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-javascripts-to-the-bottom-or-footer-in-wordpress/

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

http://unserkaiser.com/blog/2013/10/08/how-to-move-wordpress-core-javascript-to-the-footer/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Use the wp_enqueue_script.

"Once you have found the plugin or theme that is adding JavaScript in the header section, the next step is to find out where the plugin has a call for the file. In one of your theme or plugin’s PHP files you will see a call to that particular .js file.

If the plugin or theme is already using enqueuing to add JavaScript file, then all you need to do is change wp_register_script function in your plugin or theme and add true for the $in_footer parameter. "